# IIS 6 not displaying default document (default.aspx)

Tags: asp.net, iis, iis-6

We have a problem in that IIS is no longer serving finding the default document (default.aspx) on a server which has previously been working OK. We have not consciously changed the configuration of the machine.

The symptoms are that if you go to the root of an application on the machine, it displays an asp.net 404 not found page with the following text:

> The resource cannot be found.
>
> Description: HTTP 404. [etc...]
>
> Requested URL:
>   /folder/**eurl.axd/dd4414e526108f45a561b782d54f3ba2/**

I don't know what eurl.axd is, but it seems to refer to extensionless URL support for ASP.NET 4.0, but the sites in question are all ASP.NET 2.0 sites.

Default.aspx is definitely set as the default the document (and is at the top of the list) for the site.

If I manually type in /folder/default.aspx the site then works fine, so it's not a problem serving the page, but merely a problem with IIS not defaulting to that page on it's own.

Any ideas how to fix this would be appreciated as this affects a live server :(

Comment: This would be a better fit at Serverfault.com

Answer (score 8, accepted):

OK I've resolved this now. It seems it is indeed because of the extensionless URL support feature of ASP.NET 4.0. Despite the fact my sites are running .NET 2.0 sites it still seems to affect them as well (possibly because the URL filtering happens higher up?). I disabled extensionless URL support (see link) and now it's finding default.aspx pages OK.

For for more info, check this article: 
http://blogs.msdn.com/b/tmarq/archive/2010/06/18/how-to-disable-the-asp-net-v4-0-extensionless-url-feature-on-iis-6-0.aspx

Comment: God.  Thank you for figuring this out.  I've been searching for hours for keywords involving "default document 404 iis6" with no luck (too ambiguous!)  This solved my issue!

Answer (score 0):

```
To install and enable ASP.NET:
1> Click Start, and then click Control Panel.
2> Click Add or Remove Programs.
3> Click Add/Remove Windows components.
4> Double-click Application Server, and then click Details.
5> Click to select the ASP.NET check box, and then click OK.
6> Click Next.
7> Click Finish.
```